# Node.js Async Waterfall Hangs

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript, async.js

I am currently implementing an API built using Express.js, following the MVCS pattern for my design. After reading about the Async module, I came to the conclusion that it would be a good idea for me to take advantage of its powerful methods. Unfortunately, I am running into a problem I can't seem to fix, and was wondering if someone could give me some advice. Let's take look at the code:

```js
'use strict'

_ = require 'lodash'
async = require 'async'
validator = require 'express-validator'

class BaseService

  constructor: (@model, @relationships, @fields) ->

  list: (req, callback) ->
    async.waterfall [
      validate(req).bind(this),
      query.bind(this)
    ], callback

  validate = (request) ->
    valid = request
    
    (next) ->
      next null, valid
      return

  query = (valid) ->
    query = @model.find({})

    if valid.query.q
      query = query.where(valid.query.q)

    if valid.query.sort
      query = query.sort(valid.query.sort)

    if valid.query.select
      query = query.select(valid.query.select)

    # Requests hangs at this point. Any ideas why?
    (next) ->
      query.exec next
      return

module.exports = BaseService
```

Basically, I would like to first validate the query string that was passed with the request. Then, a Mongoose query is built depending on whether certain fields are present or not in the validated object. Lastly, it should execute the query and pass the results to the callback function. Here my implementation fails as it hangs, and the callback is never executed. I commented the line in the code snippet, to give you all a better idea of what is going on.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: you should use get method to authorization..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is your `query` method signature needs to accept a callback as the last argument.

```
query = (valid, callback) ->
```

For `waterfall`, the first worker function takes `(callback)`, but the rest of them take `(previousResult, callback)`.

Also, given how you are using your `query` method, it does not need to return a function as you have it doing. Just accept the callback as an argument and invoke it when ready to move on to complete the waterfall.

**Aside:** using "query" for both a method and a local variable in a coffeescript class is error prone and confusing. Use a different name for the local variable such as "modelQuery".

Comment: Thank you, Peter! That was it. I guess, I didn't quite understand how `waterfall` worked, but now it is clear. Have a great day, sir.